# Building a Raw SQL String from Linq Query Results?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I need to make a selection from a SQL Server table and concatenate the results into a SQL string so I end up with `var sqlString = "Select blah from myTable where blah blah order by blah"`:

[image]

Here's my LINQ. I'm trying to select out the columns in the order I need them & concatanate them into 1 string:

```
  var query = (from a in _Context.tbArticleTypeAssets
                      where a.ArticleType == ArticleType
                      select new {sqlQuery = a.ColSelection + "" + a.FromTable + "" + a.whereclause + "" + a.orderBY});

         string queryResult = query.ToString();
```

The result is a Linq output which I don't want. I just want the values of the strings. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

linq query will return a collection, you have to use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` to get the item :

```
 string queryResult = query.FirstOrDefault().sqlQuery;
```

better is to check for null as well:

```
string queryResult =  query.FirstOrDefault() != null ? query.FirstOrDefault().sqlQuery : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Why do I get 'sqlQuery = SELECT blah blah' in my result? On the Select new I have to give a name but I don't want the name to appear in the resulting string?

Comment: @Hardgraf the way I posted should not give you like that, and you can skip `new` which is creating anonymous object actually

Comment: I mean like : ``select a.ColSelection + "" + a.FromTable ``

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var query = _Context.tbArticleTypeAssets
        .Where(a=>a.ArticleType == ArticleType)
        .Select(a=>a.ColSelection + "" + a.FromTable + "" + a.whereclause + "" + a.orderBY)
        .ToList();
```

or if your query will always only return one record, then you can do this:

```
 var query = _Context.tbArticleTypeAssets
        .Where(a=>a.ArticleType == ArticleType)
        .Select(a=>a.ColSelection + "" + a.FromTable + "" + a.whereclause + "" + a.orderBY)
        .First();
```